# Can I charge my Samsung Gear S2 watch in UK?

Tags: uk, power, scotland

I will be traveling to the UK.

I have bought an adapter for the outlets and I do know that my phone has dual voltage support and will not need at transformer.

However, I have a Samsung Gear S2 watch that uses a [wireless charger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0179LSF7C).

**Will I need a transformer for this item?**

A USB to whatever cord plugs into the wireless charge, with the USB end going into a basic USB wall charger.

Comment: Scotland remains part of the UK and is on the same power system as the the rest of the country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can connect the wireless charger for the watch to any mains/USB adaptor and it will work (assuming the adaptor is suitable for the local voltage). You can also connect it to any computer with a USB socket. USB voltage is the same all over the world.

When you say your phone has "dual voltage support", do you mean your phone's charger? Phones are not dual voltage - they rely on the charger to adapt to the local supply.

Answer (score 3):

The wall charger transforms the 240 volt from the socket into 5 volt for the USB port. The 5 volt is what your wireless charger receives. So absolutely no problem.

This assumes that your wall charger can handle anything from 110 to 240 volt, which is a fairly safe assumption. In any case, the accepted voltage will be printed on the device.